# move the copy position in an for each - if statement

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy each value which is  `> 0.05` from `column N (5 to offset)`. Then want to to paste each value elsewhere; transposed. How do I make write it so the paste area shifts for each rendition?

```
Set ListOfCells = MainA.Worksheets("Summary_2016").Range("N5", EndCellA.Offset(14, 7))

        For Each SingleCell In ListOfCells
            If SingleCell.Value > 0.05 Then
               Range(SingleCell, SingleCell.Offset(0, -1)).Copy
                 StarterA.Worksheets("Mail").Range ("B30")

            etc
```

`StarterA.Worksheets("Mail").Range ("B30")` euh, so this is of course the `paste` command, but this has to shift every time. How do i make it dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

Try use `Offset` and `address`, say relative position is (0, 5)

```
  Tgt = SingleCell.Offset(0, 5).Address
  StarterA.Worksheets("Mail").Range (Tgt)
```

Comment: i'll look into the address function, but i don't really see how this would shift the paste range for each iteration?

Comment: The *shift* should be happen because `offset` function, **if** the `SingleCell` changed each iteration..  my code use fixed relative position (0, 5)..you can modify it to make it dynamic if needed..

Comment: but the     SingleCell range has nothing to do with WHERE i want to paste?

Comment: then..depend on what? how should we know that from current code & question?...feel free to update them..

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx This should have the answer.

Sorry Susilo, maybe my question was not clear enough, pasting should happen on worksheet mail, from b30 onwards